# Difference between Perl regular expression delimiters /.../ and #...#

Tags: regex, perl, syntax

Today I came across two different syntaxes for a Perl regular expression match.

```
#I have a date string
my $time = '2012-10-29';

#Already familiar "m//":
$t =~ m/^(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)$/

#Completely new to me m##.
$t =~ m#^(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)#/
```

Now what is the difference between `/expression/` and `#expression#`?

Comment: I think the title is not proper here... Can anyone suggest any better title for this question?

Comment: I think the title is fine. I could tell the question you were going to ask, just from it :-)

Comment: thats a nice title.. thnx @Borodin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As everone else said, you can use any delimiter after the `m`.

`/` has one special feature: you can use it by itself, e.g.

```
$string =~ /regexp/;
```

is equivalent to:

```
$string =~ m/regexp/;
```

Comment: ah at last i could at least one difference :) thnx

Comment: **Note** that if you use a single-quote, as in `$string =~ m'$5,000'` then Perl will not try to interpolate the variable for you, in the same fashion as singly-quoted strings

Answer (score 9):

Perl allows you to use pretty much any characters to delimit strings, including regexes.  This is especially useful if you need to match a pattern that contains a lot of slash characters:

```
$slashy =~ m/\/\//;   #Bad
$slashy =~ m|//|;   #Good
```

According to [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), the first of those is an example of "leaning toothpick syndrome".

Most **but not all** characters behave in the same way when escaping.  There is an important exception: `m?...?` is a special case that only matches a single time between calls to `reset()`.

Another exception: if single quotes are used for the delimiter, no variable interpolation is done.  You still have to escape `$`, though, as it is a special character matching the end of the line.

Comment: No, `m?...?` matches just once, but can look for many matches (using `m?...?g`.

Comment: @choroba, what I said is generally correct.  Is there any point to `m?...?g`?

Comment: `perl -E 'for (100,200) { say for ?(.)?g; }'`

Comment: @choroba, I am not questioning that `m??g` will match multiple times.  I just don't see a need to highlight that because it is an inherently contradictory construct that serves no purpose.  Note that even the Perl documentation doesn't mention this behavior; what I said is basically a restatement of the documentation.

Comment: The documentation says "it matches only once between calls to reset()". It does not say it "looks for a single match".

Comment: No, I didn't say everything that the documentation said, but that is an advanced feature that didn't seem relevant here (and to someone who knows about `reset()` it would be implied).  I really don't see what's wrong with saying it "only looks for a single match of the pattern".  That is what `m??` is intended to do, and that is what it does in any normal case.

Comment: It feels like you left something out in your description of m??. All regexes match only once, unless otherwise instructed.

Comment: @choroba, you were right. I apologize for arguing about this.  I have corrected the post.

Comment: @TLP, thanks, you finally made me realize what choroba was trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing except what you have to escape in the regex. You can use any pair of matched characters you like.

```
$string = "http://example.com/";
$string =~ m!http://!;
$string =~ m#http://!#;
$string =~ m{http://};
$string =~ m/http:\/\//;
```

Comment: oh seems lots of variations available... and its all same !!

Comment: I got the reason of variations from others' comment. Thnx anyway.

Comment: @Samiron — You didn't get the reason for the variations from the second sentence in this answer?

Comment: ah yes... surely :).. it told the same so quickly i missed it.. thnx

Answer (score 3):

After the match or search/replace operator (the `m` and `s`, respectively) you can use any character as the delimiter, e.g. the `#` in your case. This also works with pairs of parenthesis: `s{ abc (.*) def }{ DEF $1 ABC }x`.

Advantages are that you don't have to escape the `/` (but the actual delimiter characters, of course). It's often used for clarity, especially when dealing with things like paths or protocols.

Comment: oh its cool !! it means i can use any non-alphanum character as delimiter, right? cause i should be using any letter or number as the delimiter.

Comment: @sam Pretty much. If you by "should" meant "should not". Consider the often used obfuscation substitution: `s;;;;`

Comment: ah yes.. it will be "should not".. dont know why.. im typing everything wrong today.. :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference; the "/" and "#" characters are used as delimiters for the expression. They simply mark the "boundary" of the expression, but are not part of the expression. In theory you can use most non-alphanumeric characters as a delimiter. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) is a link to the PHP manual (It doesn't matter that it is the PHP manual, the Regex syntax is the same, I just like it because it explains well) on Perl compatible regular expression syntax; read the part about delimiters

Comment: ah yes.. that link explains fine.. I failed to google about this with proper keyword.